# Image made of shapes - terminology + software?

Tags: image

I've often seen images that look like the following example

[image]

Q1) is there a term for such an image?

Q2) What common software is used to convert a real photo (e.g. human face) to be composed of such shapes? (or even an online service)

Comment: I think [Graphic Design SE](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) might be a better place to ask this question since we are dealing mostly with coding and algorithms here. So chances are good that you get a quicker and better response there.

Comment: It's a triangulation with a constant colour within each triangle. However you can see that the shadows are not triangles. For algorithms see: https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Adaptive-image-approximation-by-linear-splines-over-Demaret-Iske/a862a9fbb1945e784a9955311f7d6c5422ff8808

Comment: @wychmaster ok thanks, I did see GDSE prior to posting here but wasn't quite sure.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the answer from GD. I close the question here. Everybody who wants to contribute more can do this on GD.

Answer (score 1):

It's called low poly

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_poly

(thanks to a user on GD.SE)
https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/155190/image-made-of-shapes-terminology-software